# Converting Three Word String into Two Strings

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to convert three names in a cell to two cells?

For example A1 "John Dory" becomes A1 "John" B1 "Dory". The issue is when there are three words (middle names) it's automatically doing it for three cells. If it could be either the middle name in A1 or B1 that would be fine.

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use the `Text to Columns` method the way you want to given your delimiter being present multiple times.

This code will take the values in `Column A` and return the **First Name** in `Column B` and return the **Second *and* Last Name** in `Column C`

### Explanation

1. Load Array (`Arr`) from row 2 to last row (`LRow`)
2. Extract desired strings using the Excel functions `Left` and `Right`. `InStr` is VBAs version of the Excel function `Search`. `Chr(32)` is simply the chr code for *space*
3. Output values on corresponding rows. Since arrays default with the first index of 0, you will need to use `i + 1` when relating the index to the row number, else your values will all be offset by 1.

Adjust the columns as needed and the sheet name on the 3rd line. This also assumes a single-row header exists

---

```
Sub Custom_Delim()

Dim i As Long, LRow As Long, Arr
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Arr = ws.Range("A2:A" & LRow).Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        ws.Range("B" & i + 1) = Left(Arr(i, 1), InStr(Arr(i, 1), Chr(32)) - 1)
        ws.Range("C" & i + 1) = Right(Arr(i, 1), Len(Arr(i, 1)) - InStr(Arr(i, 1), Chr(32)))
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use the `Text to Columns` the way you want to (multiple delimiters exist in one string). This is using an array so it should be pretty quick

Comment: Just some insight - I would recommend placing these values into an array and writing the array to your sheet just once. This took 6.6 seconds to complete on 100k rows (which isn't bad) - and I think this could be under a second if you write the array to your sheet.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs nice! I've actually never done that. Will study your answer and try to re-create

Comment: I'll give it ago! Thank you so much folks

Comment: Hi Urdearboy, I tried your code. I receive an error invalid procedure call or arguement; ws.Range("B" & i + 1) = Left(Arr(i, 1), InStr(Arr(i, 1), Chr(32)) - 1)

Comment: This was tested and working fine. We can trouble shoot if you would like, but @K.Dᴀᴠɪs solution is better (runs faster per his comment on this post). I would give his a look and accept his solution if it works for ya!

Comment: Thanks! Just tried K.Davis. It works. However, for some strange reason if it's the first sheet but not 4th or 5th. Any reason?

Comment: My code explicitly looks for the first sheet. You can set the ws variable to active sheet to correct

Comment: Done. Cheers mate

Answer (score 3):

Essentially you are placing all your values into an array, splitting them into a 2D array and writing them back to the worksheet all at once.

> ### Tested with 100k rows:
>
> Test 1 = 0.67 seconds
>   Test 2 = 0.66 seconds
>   Test 3 = 0.67 seconds

```
Option Explicit

Sub customText2Col()

    Dim startTime As Double

    startTime = Timer

    Dim startRng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    With ws
        Set startRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(lastRow(ws), "A"))
    End With

    ' Place startRng's values into an array
    Dim rawTxtArr, newTxtArr()
    rawTxtArr = startRng
    ReDim newTxtArr(1 To UBound(rawTxtArr), 1 To 2)

    Dim i As Long, x As Long, tmpArr
    For i = LBound(rawTxtArr) To UBound(rawTxtArr)
        tmpArr = Split(rawTxtArr(i, 1))
        newTxtArr(i, 1) = tmpArr(0)
        For x = 1 To UBound(tmpArr)
            newTxtArr(i, 2) = Trim(newTxtArr(i, 2) & " " & tmpArr(x))
        Next x
        Erase tmpArr
    Next i

    ws.Range("A1:B" & lastRow(ws)).Value = newTxtArr

    MsgBox Timer - startTime

End Sub

Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```